# Are there optional arguments without default values, that can "not exist" unless passed/specified/used?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method

```
public void Foo(String someString = "A String")
{
    Console.WriteLine(someString);
}
```

That is being called within another method

```
// No arguments unless one is specifically passed when called
public void Bar(String anotherString = )
{
    Foo(anotherString);
}
```

You can probably already tell what I'm trying to do here, I'd like to only pass a String if a value is given when calling `Bar()`. If no argument is passed for `Bar()` I'd like to omit `anotherString` entirely so that the default values of `Foo()` are used instead.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are all string values valid to pass to `Bar`? Is `null` valid?

Answer (score 3):

Use an overload:

```
public void Foo(String someString = "A String")
{
    Console.WriteLine(someString);
}

public void Bar(String anotherString = "a")
{
    Foo(anotherString);
}

public void Bar()
{
    Foo();
}
```

Comment: This is a bit nitpicky, but consider making the string argument to the first `Bar(string)` method non-optional.  Leaving it this way may confuse a future maintainer of this code.  They may wonder what the purpose of the default value `"a"` might have been, and (mistakenly per @Nomnom's desire) change the overload of `Bar()` to call `Foo("a");`.